# Envoy stuck in failed_active_hc for uptream

Tags: envoyproxy

I am trying setup Envoy outside k8s as load balancing proxy for gRPC service. I also use health check for gRPC:

```
# cluster setup

connect_timeout: 0.25s
type: static
health_checks:                            
  - timeout: 1s                           
    interval: 1s                          
    unhealthy_interval: 1s                
    initial_jitter: 1s                    
    unhealthy_threshold: 3                
    healthy_threshold: 1                  
    always_log_health_check_failures: true
    event_log_path: /dev/stdout           
    grpc_health_check: {}
```

Problem is: when on Envoy startup upstream is unavailable, after this upstream actually become available it takes too much time for Envoy to start health checking that upstream (like 10-30 seconds).

After upstream become healthy for the first time, health check works properly and upstream enabled/disabled according to provided parameters.

I enabled debug logs, there is nothing interesting related to healthchecks, actually there is nothing for some time, until health check requests started

One of my theories is that it is related to `static` cluster type, but I have no idea how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There is 2 health check parameters: `no_traffic_interval` and `no_traffic_healthy_interval`, which was used on startup, since service didn't received any traffic, and it waited for 60 seconds (by default) to start sending health checks. When I set them to the same value as usual `interval`, everything works fine.